# Linux: Finding the path of the default PDF viewer in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, pdf

I want to get the path of the user's default PDF viewer within a bash script.

I know I can xdg-open/exo-open to open the file in the viewer, but I just want to know what the viewer is. I don't want to actually open it. For example, if I ran this on an Ubuntu system I would want to be able to determine that the user's PDF viewer is `/usr/bin/evince`.

I've figured out that I can do `xdg-mime query default application/pdf` to get the .desktop file, but I don't know how to take that result and get to the path of the viewer (without copying the `search_desktop_file()` function from xdg-open, which doesn't seem like the best way to go).

Comment: What's the output from `xdg-mime query default application/pdf` exactly? `evince.desktop`?

Comment: Yes, `evince.desktop` for me, but of course it could be a number of different things depending on the system.

Comment: Sure. I was just checking that it returned *just* the bare `*.desktop` filename. (I don't have access to a system with `xdg-mime` at the moment.)

Answer (score 1):

I´m not sure if this is the best way, probably not, but it works :)

```
#!/bin/sh
DESKTOPFILE=`xdg-mime query default application/pdf`
DESKTOPPATH='~/.local/share/applications/'
if [ ! -f $DESKTOPPATH$DESKTOPFILE ];
then
        DESKTOPPATH='/usr/share/applications/'
fi
if [ ! -f $DESKTOPPATH$DESKTOPFILE ];
then
        DESKTOPPATH='/usr/local/share/applications/'
fi
EXECNAME=`cat $DESKTOPPATH$DESKTOPFILE | grep ^Exec | cut -d '=' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
EXECPATH=`which $EXECNAME`
echo $EXECPATH
```

Comment: That file could be in a number of different directories though. xdg-open searches in `~/.local/share`, `/usr/local/share`, `/usr/share` and then a handful of dirs within each of those. So I'm basically back to copying/pasting large chunks of xdg-open to get the path of the desktop file.

Comment: You are right, it could be in this two other places, with the user folder taking precedence. Edited the answer for looking at them.

As far as I undertand, tought, the desktop files are only on this folders, not in subfolders of those (If Im wrong please confirm this information, because docs I´ve read and real cases I´ve checked do not have subfolders on thos dirs). So this should work now.

Answer (score 0):

May be you just need to remove the suffix:

```
basename $(xdg-mime query default application/pdf) .desktop
```

Enclose in `which $()`, if you need the full path.

Comment: `which` will not be able to find the full path of a .desktop file. It works on executables that are in $PATH.

In this case it would be better to query paths that hold .desktop files by default and locate the desired one. Then, query the desired file for the `Exec=...` key to find out which program it actually launches.

Comment: @bool3max: which is the output of `which $(basename $(xdg-mime query default application/pdf) .desktop) ` for you?

Comment: Your answer assumes that the executable name of the application that handles PDF viewing is the same as its associated `.desktop` file. 

This is not always the case, and it shouldn't be relied upon.

Moreover some applications may not even come with an associated `.desktop` file.

Comment: @bool3max: First you said   my solution _cannot_ not work; now you say that it _could not_ work for the generality of cases. As for the latter,  the freedesktop.org specifications state that:  "`query default mimetype` returns the default application that the desktop environment uses for opening files of type mimetype. The default application is identified by its `*.desktop` file." If we do not rely on X specs, on what do we rely?